# CSS animation - Unwanted stutter when mouse over (Firefox only)

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have set up a page with several panels which are revealed when the user clicks a button, and then the page animates to the # of the next slide using jquery.

There are also several elements that fade into view using css animation just as the page settles on it's new position.

In firefox only - if the mouse is over an element on the new panel as the fade animation happens there is an ugly flash/stutter of the animation, like it is firing multiple times. if the mouse is somewhere else it works as expected.

```
<section id="slide-2" class="content page-2 hidden">
  <div class="row">
    <article class="copy page-1-copy">
      <h2>
        The animated elements flash if mouse enters during animation.
      </h2>

      <a><button class="stat3 fadeIn animated alt" value="Sign up">Really?
        </button></a>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbGqgd?editors=010

The pen above has a simple version of the page. If you click the trigger button and leave the mouse where it is the bug should be apprent.

(There is some CSS that is redundant in there as I ran out of patience whilst chopping it down - Please ignore)

Comment: You can ignore the code snippet for the most part and go straight to th codepen.

Comment: what about prefix `-moz-` ? or are you using `prefixfreejs`

Comment: Yeah I have tried prefix `-moz-` on everything on the main build, firefox dev tools is ignoring it and generally it doesn't seem to be needed (caniuse etc).

Comment: I should add i am using animate.css although I will dispense with that closer to launch.